# shipping method added by qbxml does not appearing in quickbooks desktop UI

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I have added **ShipMethodRef** and **ShipDate** by qbxml query but in Quickbooks Desktop it does not appearing for that sales receipt or invoice.

This is request that I am making to add shipInfo :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="7.0"?><QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceModRq>
      <InvoiceMod>
        <TxnID>3D4B-1071531138</TxnID>
        <EditSequence>1576429335</EditSequence>
        <RefNumber>1060</RefNumber>
        <ShipDate>2018-04-09</ShipDate>
        <ShipMethodRef>
          <ListID>80000009-1608014757</ListID>
          <FullName>DHL</FullName>
        </ShipMethodRef>
      </InvoiceMod>
    </InvoiceModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

This is response showing that shipInfo is added successfully for this invoice :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs>
        <InvoiceModRs statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
            <InvoiceRet>
                <TxnID>3D4B-1071531138</TxnID>
                <TimeCreated>2003-12-15T23:32:18+00:00</TimeCreated>
                <TimeModified>2020-12-15T06:51:08+00:00</TimeModified>
                <EditSequence>1608015068</EditSequence>
                <TxnNumber>792</TxnNumber>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>820000-1071531106</ListID>
                    <FullName>Dunn, Eric C.W.:Utility Shed</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <ClassRef>
                    <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
                    <FullName>New Construction</FullName>
                </ClassRef>
                <ARAccountRef>
                    <ListID>40000-933270541</ListID>
                    <FullName>Accounts Receivable</FullName>
                </ARAccountRef>
                <TemplateRef>
                    <ListID>E0000-1071499861</ListID>
                    <FullName>Rock Castle Invoice</FullName>
                </TemplateRef>
                <TxnDate>2020-09-22</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>1060</RefNumber>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>Dunn, Eric C.W.</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>97401 N. Liberty Ln</Addr2>
                    <City>Bayshore</City>
                    <State>CA</State>
                    <PostalCode>94326</PostalCode>
                </BillAddress>
                <BillAddressBlock>
                    <Addr1>Dunn, Eric C.W.</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>97401 N. Liberty Ln</Addr2>
                    <Addr3>Bayshore,  CA  94326</Addr3>
                </BillAddressBlock>
                <ShipAddress>
                    <Addr1>Dunn, Eric C.W.</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>97401 N. Liberty Ln</Addr2>
                    <City>Bayshore</City>
                    <State>CA</State>
                    <PostalCode>94326</PostalCode>
                </ShipAddress>
                <ShipAddressBlock>
                    <Addr1>Dunn, Eric C.W.</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>97401 N. Liberty Ln</Addr2>
                    <Addr3>Bayshore, CA 94326</Addr3>
                </ShipAddressBlock>
                <IsPending>false</IsPending>
                <IsFinanceCharge>false</IsFinanceCharge>
                <DueDate>2021-09-22</DueDate>
                <ShipDate>2018-04-09</ShipDate>
                <ShipMethodRef>
                    <ListID>80000009-1608014757</ListID>
                    <FullName>DHL</FullName>
                </ShipMethodRef>
                <Subtotal>2400.00</Subtotal>
                <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                    <ListID>2E0000-933272656</ListID>
                    <FullName>San Tomas</FullName>
                </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <SalesTaxPercentage>7.75</SalesTaxPercentage>
                <SalesTaxTotal>69.75</SalesTaxTotal>
                <AppliedAmount>-2469.75</AppliedAmount>
                <BalanceRemaining>0.00</BalanceRemaining>
                <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
                <CustomerMsgRef>
                    <ListID>50000-933272660</ListID>
                    <FullName>Thank you for your business.</FullName>
                </CustomerMsgRef>
                <IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
                <IsToBeEmailed>false</IsToBeEmailed>
                <CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>
                    <ListID>10000-999022286</ListID>
                    <FullName>Tax</FullName>
                </CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>
                <LinkedTxn>
                    <TxnID>3D95-1071497099</TxnID>
                    <TxnType>ReceivePayment</TxnType>
                    <TxnDate>2020-09-23</TxnDate>
                    <RefNumber>2957</RefNumber>
                    <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
                    <Amount>-2469.75</Amount>
                </LinkedTxn>
                <InvoiceLineGroupRet>
                    <TxnLineID>3D4D-1071531138</TxnLineID>
                    <ItemGroupRef>
                        <ListID>400000-1071530168</ListID>
                        <FullName>A1 Custom Storage Shed</FullName>
                    </ItemGroupRef>
                    <Desc>Custom Storage Building - Model A1 - 14'x10'</Desc>
                    <IsPrintItemsInGroup>false</IsPrintItemsInGroup>
                    <TotalAmount>2400.00</TotalAmount>
                    <InvoiceLineRet>
                        <TxnLineID>3D4E-1071531138</TxnLineID>
                        <ItemRef>
                            <ListID>1C0000-933272656</ListID>
                            <FullName>Lumber:Rough</FullName>
                        </ItemRef>
                        <Rate>900.00</Rate>
                        <ClassRef>
                            <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
                            <FullName>New Construction</FullName>
                        </ClassRef>
                        <Amount>900.00</Amount>
                        <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                            <ListID>10000-999022286</ListID>
                            <FullName>Tax</FullName>
                        </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                    </InvoiceLineRet>
                    <InvoiceLineRet>
                        <TxnLineID>3D4F-1071531138</TxnLineID>
                        <ItemRef>
                            <ListID>3F0000-1071530163</ListID>
                            <FullName>Labor</FullName>
                        </ItemRef>
                        <Rate>1500.00</Rate>
                        <ClassRef>
                            <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
                            <FullName>New Construction</FullName>
                        </ClassRef>
                        <Amount>1500.00</Amount>
                        <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                            <ListID>20000-999022286</ListID>
                            <FullName>Non</FullName>
                        </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                    </InvoiceLineRet>
                </InvoiceLineGroupRet>
            </InvoiceRet>
        </InvoiceModRs>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Same like query I am using to update Sales Order and Sales Receipt and grtting same like response as above.

This is screenshot from Quickbooks Desktop for this invoice :
[image: Invoice 1060 Screenshot]

**Why does Quickbooks Desktop does not showing me that ShipDate and ShipMethod for any invoices?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify your invoice template to see this information.

Comment: Changing the template from Rock Castle Invoice to Intuit Product Invoice solved my problem. Thanks @William Lorfing